# Как не импортировать модули несколько раз?

Tags: python, оптимизация

Сам вопрос в теме, а контекст такой. Например я написал модуль, который использует другой модуль, допустим из стандартной библиотеки, и импортирую его в главную программу.

Вот модуль(пусть rnd.py):

```
def func():
    return rand_int = random.randint(0, 100)
```

Вот программа:

```
import random
import rnd

print(rnd.func())
```

Но питон напишет ошибку, что random в модуле rnd.py не определен.
Получается нужно написать import random в модуле rnd.py. А если кто-то другой захочет использовать этот модуль и кроме импорта rnd.py сам по себе импортирует random? а если таких модулей несколько? Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Тут не Си и не PHP. Пространства имён разных модулей полностью разделены и никак не пересекаются. Вспомнив, что модули в питоне — такие же объекты, как и всё остальное, мы можем творить, например, такой ужас:

```
## Файл rnd.py ##
import os as random
print(random.listdir('.'))


## Файл program.py ##
import random
import rnd  # вывод: [содержимое текущего каталога]

# random в пространстве имён в этом месте никак не тронут:
print(random.randrange(2))  # вывод: 0 или 1

# Мы можем лезть в пространство имён модуля:
print(rnd.random.path.isdir('.'))  # вывод: True
```

(но так жестоко переименовывать модули, разумеется, не надо, это только пример)

За производительность беспокоиться не надо: модули загружаются и инциализируются всего один раз (и в Python 3 перезагрузить их нельзя):

```
import rnd as r1  # вывод: [содержимое текущего каталога]
import rnd as r2  # ничего не выведет, модуль уже загружен
print(r1 is r2)  # вывод: True
# мы просто загрузили один и тот же модуль в две разные переменные
```

Словарь всех загруженных на данный момент модулей можно посмотреть в переменной `sys.modules` (естественно, не забыв импортировать сам модуль `sys`).

В общем, импортировать одни и те же модули для их использования в разных модулях нужно, и бояться этого совсем не стоит.